# Selenium can't click a button python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Can you tell me why selenium can't click a button. I tried xpath, id, class, text and nothing.
i get info that there is no such element or sth like that but in firefox i can see that there's an item the name is the same. No idea whats wrong.

```
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 3500)")
sleep(1)
#self.action.move_to_element(przycisk).click(sprawdz).perform()
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='sprawdz']").click();
#self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("ok").click();
```

[image: button on the website]

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.btn-large#sprawdz").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-large' and @id='sprawdz']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-large#sprawdz"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-large' and @id='sprawdz']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Update

As a last resort you can use `execute_script()` method as follows:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.btn.btn-large#sprawdz"))))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-large' and @id='sprawdz']"))))
  ```

Comment: unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: @MikołajK Checkout the updated answer and let me know the result

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: Dismissed user prompt dialog: Gotowe? Można sprawdzić?

Comment: this Message: Dismissed user prompt dialog: Gotowe? Można sprawdzić? is a pop up/ alert after clicking the button. but the script doesn't click it. I can only manually click the button and then i see an alert asking if i'm sure i want to check. Maybe this alert is a problem

Comment: @MikołajK This solution was to click on the button with text as **SPRAWDZ** nothing more or less. We aren't sure about the **pop up** / **alert**. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='sprawdz']")
self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: or try this self.driver.find_element_by_id('sprawdz').click()